# Hide value 00:00:00 TimeSpan in Column of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, timespan

I have a `DataGridView` with this `DataTable`

```
var dTable = new DataTable();
dTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
dTable.Columns.Add("Time", typeof(TimeSpan));
```

It may happen that there is a `TimeSpan` with a value of **00:00:00**.

Is there any possibility of not displaying the **00:00:00** value in the column as happens with the `DateTime` if the value is `MinValue` type?

Comment: If OP want to check timespan is 00:00:00, then he can try with `(TimeSpan)grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.Equals(TimeSpan.Zero)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use CellFormatting event in DataGridView, to change displayed value without changing underlying data (TimeSpan.Zero is "00:00:00" value)

```
private void Grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0) return;
    var grid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ValueType == typeof(TimeSpan) &&
        TimeSpan.Zero == (TimeSpan)grid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value)
    {
        e.Value = " ";
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but by doing so I then lose the ability to order the column correctly, right?

Comment: underlying data doesn't change. there will still be "00:00:00"